# Python subprocess Popen windows error code

Tags: python, windows

I'm running a py script on a separate process via subprocess.Popen
Then I call

```
(proc_out, proc_err) = proc.communicate
```

and also read the return code

```
proc.returncode
```

While proc_err is None the return code is *3221225738*

Does anyone know what it means or how to get an understandable error?
Thanks

Comment: chances are that is the positive representation of a 32bit negative number?

Comment: but what does it mean as a return code of an execution?

Comment: it may be a value relative to the os or the process started.   the  hex value of the number is this:  ‭C000 010A‬

Comment: Added an answer.  you might want to give more context on the calls made (more surrounding code).

Comment: `STATUS_PROCESS_IS_TERMINATING` (0xC000_010A) would normally be translated to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5) for a WinAPI call. Either the process failed during initialization, or it died on an unhandled exception while running.  Offhand I can't think of a system call that would raise an exception with that status code, so I'll take a wild guess that something went wrong that caused the console host process (conhost.exe) to terminate while the base API was setting up the console connection. Try running it with `creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS` and `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely meaning of the return code is that its the HEX value C000010A which I found a description of this for:

```
Error code0xC000010A
TypeWindows NT Status Code
DescriptionSTATUS_PROCESS_IS_TERMINATING
Comments

EventID.Net
In programming terms, this is a message that is returned when a function is trying to obtain a reference (a handle) to a certain process but that process is actually terminating (shutting down).
```

best guess is its trying to access the proces after it has finished....

Comment: debugging further I found this other error:  (5, 'AssignProcessToJobObject', 'Access is denied.')

I'm using 

win32job.AssignProcessToJobObject(self.job_object, hProcess)